# Recommit file on Git after push

Tags: git

I started using Git recently. I have a question regarding commit.

How can I commit a modified file after the push if there are build errors? I am doing the following:

```
git commit -a - Here I added commit message and committed modified files (say 5 files)
git push BranchName
```

After pushing my changes, the build started on the build server.

Later I got a build error. I identified the error and fixed it by modifying one file.

How do I commit only one file over the existing push?

`git status` shows only 1 file modified. But `git commit --amend` seems to only change commit message and `git commit -a` creates a new commit with only 1 file ( and it is linked to the previous commit)

Comment: The same way you do any commit - add the file(s), commit them, push. If you `git status` what's the output?

Comment: This is one of many reasons that I recommend *avoiding* `git commit -a`. It lets you avoid learning about Git's index (aka staging area) for a while ... but as soon as you are doing something tricky, *whap* you're hit in the face with Git's index. You *have* to learn about it. Once you do, you don't need `git commit -a` (though you can use it whenever it's convenient).

Answer (score 0):

Each commit contains *all* your files. What you are committing is the state of the whole project. The history is just a graph of these snapshots. If you pushed a commit (snapshot) and the project changes to a more desirable state, simply make a new commit (snapshot) and push that.

That's what commits are for: each new commit is a "more desirable" state (ostensibly; of course it is possible to make things worse, but then you make things better later, just as you are doing).

So just `git add` the modified file, `git commit`, and `git push`.